# Import of print compositions in QGIS 3.0

Tags: print-composer, qgis-3

I installed QGIS 3.0 last week and would like to edit my projects with it. However when I try to import my saved print compositions the following message appears (see picture below).

Can you tell my why that is or how I can save my compositions in QGIS 2.18 so I can use them in QGIS 3.0?

[image: Error Message in print composer 3.0]

Comment: There have been _major_ changes in QGIS 3 which differ greatly with QGIS 2.18. I would suggest re-creating it in QGIS 3 from scratch.

Comment: Ok, of course thats a possibility, but it means a high amount of work - which I think is unnecessary (I created the print compositions to save time). I already tried creating a print composition with 10 pages using the content of my saved ones and unfortunately just copying doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

After trying and trying how to import and / or copy my compositions I found a rather easy way to open them in QGIS 3:

if you still have an older version of QGIS on your computer open all the print compositions you want to edit in QGIS 3 and save your project with the opened compositions. Now if you open your project in QGIS 3 all the compositions should be there in the "Layout Manager".

As far as I can see, every feature and text and picture (even SVGs) is shown in the compositions in QGIS 3.